# iTextSharp - Is it possible to set a different alignment in the same cell for text

Tags: pdf, itext

In one cell and on the same line, I must add two text (name and date).
The first snippet of text must be on the left page side, the second one on the right, and everything must be in one line.
I've tried used `Paragraph`s, `Chunk`s and `Phrase`s but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to separate two pieces of text in the same `Phrase` or `Paragraph`, you have to create a `Chunk` I often refer to as *glue*:

```
Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
```

You can use this `glue` like this:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    Phrase p = new Phrase();
    p.add("Left");
    p.add(glue);
    p.add("Right");
    table.addCell(p);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the special `Chunk` we've created separates the `Strings` `"left"` and `"right"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two paragraphs, chunks or phrases. If you are trying to do it with just one of the three, you are limited. Just define another text field to be added to the page. You can use any combination of three, and set the location on the page to reflect your requirements.